# Tasked update doesn't work at reboot time, giving me this error message: "Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com' "

Tags: bash, ubuntu, server, updates

I am setting up an ubuntu server and one of the things I need to do is have all my installed packages updated at reboot time. I used crontab for this. If I run the script manually it works fine, but when I reboot my server it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

What I suspect is that my network is not up yet, immediately after reboot and I'm guessing it doesn't take the same amount of time to get it up and running every reboot so that's why the script works sometimes?

This is the main part in my update script:

```
apt-get update -y | tee -a /var/log/update_script.log
apt-get upgrade -y | tee -a /var/log/update_script.log
```

This is my crontab task:

```
@reboot /home/shendric/update.sh
```

So I want this script to run every time I boot/reboot my server and I need the output to be put in a log file. Anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it by putting

```
sleep 10
```

in my code to see if the network needed some time to start up and the script worked every time.
So I just put a condition in my script that checked for internet connection.
If the network isn't up yet, it waits 10 seconds. Otherwise it updates as usual.
Here's my code:

```
if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null;
then
    update_function
else
    sleep 10
    update_function
fi
```

Hope this helps anyone who might encounter the same problem!